# The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled

Tags: docusignapi

I am using Docusign developer account.Whenever I try to make the first api call, I getting the error The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled.

```
<DocuSignCredentials>
<Username>
   mss.mohitchauhan@gmail.com
</Username>
<Password>
   xxxxxx
</Password>
<IntegratorKey>
   xxxxxxxxxxx
</IntegratorKey>
</DocuSignCredentials>
```

Comment: What endpoint are you using? A full post of your call (blanked out credential values) would also help solve what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using production endpoint. Use the demo endpoint to test your code. (https://demo.docusign.net/restapi)

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the same error. For me it was because my property casing was wrong.